# Kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin enum generation

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm having a hard time generating proper swagger 2.0 yaml documentation using kongchen swagger-maven-plugin. My problem happens when have 2 classes using same enum class.

```
public enum Enum {
   A,B,C
}

public class First {
   public Enum e;
}

public class Second {
   public Enum e;
}
```

This will generate swagger.yaml file containing:

```
definitions:
  First:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      e:
        type: "string"
        enum:
        - "A"
        - "B"
        - "C"
  Second:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      e:
        type: "string"
        enum:
        - "A"
        - "B"
        - "C"
```

However, I would like it to generate just one enum model definition and reference the type in objects' fields. Something like this:

```
definitions:
  First:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      $ref: "#/definitions/Enum"

  Second:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      e:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Enum"

  Enum:
    type: "string"
    enum:
        - "A"
        - "B"
        - "C"
```

Is there any way to achieve this? This way my generated client generates multiple inner enum classes with same values.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Comment: I am looking for a way to workaround this as well. Does anyone have any solutions?